# how to manage different sessions in different tabs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

how to manage different sessions in different tabs ?

I just want that when user open other tab and login again then previous tab also managed ther previous session and new tab manage new Session.

in MVC or ASP.Net

Any help appreciable

Comment: well..yes i also encountered the same problem ....for this purpose you can just make ajax call from your layout page with in any specified time say after 1 min or so with settimeout in jquery and see for sessions..

Answer (score 0):

Include the following code on pageload:

```
 if (!IsPostback) {
//Generate a new PageiD'
ViewState("_PageID") = (new Random()).Next().ToString();
 }
```

When you save something to your Session State, include the PageID:

```
 Session(ViewState("_PageID").ToString() & "CheckBoxes") = D
```

Or here is another way,
Include following code in webconfig file.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<sessionState cookieless="true"
  regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,Yes you can manage different session in different tabs.You have to create guid route which will maintain a guid for each tab.
There is complete article ***[Get an unique session in each browser tab](http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/02/get-a-unique-session-in-each-browser-tab/)*** by Jonas Gauffin.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Include some excerpts from the link. Refer [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/217907).